# Linker error after making minor change to Core Data model

Tags: ios, linker-errors, cocoapods, magicalrecord

I'm starting a new project that built fine after I added MagicalRecord via CocoaPods (my first experience with CocoaPods).

Right after constructing my data model, I received an error telling me I had not included an expected inverse relationship between two entities. I went into the data model and corrected this, and now I'm receiving this error upon rebuild:

```
Ld /Users/myName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-ewvswzrvrwxktphioghlirgkuyju/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectName.app/ProjectName normal x86_64
    cd "/Users/myName/Desktop/Everything from DT 1:20:15/App projects/WMMG/ProjectName"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -L/Users/myName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-ewvswzrvrwxktphioghlirgkuyju/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/myName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-ewvswzrvrwxktphioghlirgkuyju/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/myName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-ewvswzrvrwxktphioghlirgkuyju/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ProjectName.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -lPods-MagicalRecord -framework CoreData -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=8.1 -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/myName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-ewvswzrvrwxktphioghlirgkuyju/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ProjectName_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/myName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-ewvswzrvrwxktphioghlirgkuyju/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectName.app/ProjectName

ld: library not found for -lPods-MagicalRecord
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The error seems to point explicitly to a problem with the Linker and pods. The problem is that I have no experience debugging linker problems, and feel very out of my depth when the references I find to similar problems start talking about "dependencies" and such. It seems obvious that the MagicalRecord libraries aren't being found, but I don't know how the change I made might have caused the problem, and am even less sure how to correct it.

Can someone help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's very odd that Core Data would trigger this. To fix the link issue try typing `pod install` (cd to the folder containing your project workspace first).

Comment: Just tried it, then quit Xcode, started the project again, cleaned, built, and received the same error message.

Comment: Try wiping the DerivedData folder too? You're opening the xcworkspace not the xcproject, right?

Comment: Uh no. I opened the project from the Xcode startup window. Should I open the workspace from the finder instead?

Comment: Ok, I just closed the project and opened the workspace instead. It builds with no errors, but has 14 undeclared selector warnings which were not there before, all from 3 MagicalRecord files.

Comment: When using Cocoapods, the xcworkspace is always used. That will bring in both your own project and the pods (they are both child projects within the workspace). I'm glad it's building!